# PHP: How can i get my exceptions from my functions file into my class-file and then give it to my front-end?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, throw

For a schoolproject we need to make a php project containing a registration form, OOP-written in PHP. But I'm stuck with the error handling of my form.

The following works:

1. I made the form in my register.php file
2. I send the data to my
   User.class.php file
3. It checks the form in my function.inc.php
   file  thanks to my `canRegister()` function

This works fine; when the form isn't filled in correctly, it won't add the data to my database. The problem I'm having, has to do with the exceptions in my front end (register.php).

So the Exception are currently caught in my User.class.php but I don't know how I can 'transfer' this data from my class to my register.php file since the data is again situated in a try catch situation.

Functions.inc.php file:

```
{
    if ($item1 != $item2) {
        throw new Exception('Passwords are not matching');

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function canRegister($email, $password1, $password2)
{
    try {
        isEqual($password1, $password2);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

User.class.php file:

```
public function register()
        {
            $password = Security::hash($this->password);
            if (canRegister($this->email, $this->password, $this->passwordConfirmation)) {
                try {
                    $conn = Db::getInstance();
                    $statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO user(firstName, lastName, userName, email, password) values (:firstName, :lastName, :userName, :email, :password)');
                    $statement->bindParam(':firstName', $this->firstName);
                    $statement->bindParam(':lastName', $this->lastName);
                    $statement->bindParam(':userName', $this->userName);
                    $statement->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
                    $statement->bindParam(':password', $password);
                    $result = $statement->execute();

                    return $result;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
            }
        }
```

register.php file:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $user = new User();

    $user->setFirstName($_POST['firstName']);
    $user->setLastName($_POST['lastName']);
    $user->setUserName($_POST['userName']);
    $user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
    $user->setPassword($_POST['password']);
    $user->setPasswordConfirmation($_POST['passwordConfirmation']);

    if ($user->register()) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user->getEmail();
    //header('location: index.php');
    } else {
        $result = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I expect to get a result in my $result variable so I can echo that to my front end.

Thanks in advance,
Wannes

Comment: Since you are already using session variables why store the error messages there? If `$_SESSION['errors']` is set or is not empty you can display them

Comment: Thx. I will try it that way :)